# Ignore # (hashtag) within \newcommand

Tags: macros

I am using the `lyluatex` package to integrate LilyPond to LaTeX. I created the following command for conveniently outputting correct-size Figured Bass within a text:

```
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{%
    \raisebox{-2pt}{%
        \lilypond{%
        #(set-global-staff-size 18)%
        \figures {#1}
        }%
    }%
}
```

The problem is `#(set-global-staff-size 18)` is not really an argument, whereas a LilyPond command. The code does compile, but I have to tell it to skip the invalid argument every time.

`\detokenize` and `\string` have proved ineffective.

Any suggestions as how to pass the hashtag to LilyPond while having LaTeX ignore it?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `#` can be catcode 12 going into `\lilypad`, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{%
    \raisebox{-2pt}{%
        \prelilypond{%
        ##(set-global-staff-size 18)%
        figures {#1}% I removed the backslash for this non-working example.
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand\prelilypond[1]{\expandafter\lilypond\expandafter{\string#1}}

\def\lilypond#1{#1}

\fig{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the `#` must be catcode 6, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{%
    \raisebox{-2pt}{%
        \lilypond{%
        ##(set-global-staff-size 18)%
        figures {#1}% I removed the backslash for this non-working example.
        }%
    }%
}

\def\lilypond#1{\string#1}

\fig{1}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, in these examples, I redefined `\lilypad` to something verbose, so I didn't have to perform an actual musical example.

Comment: By simply introducing a double hashtag, it worked properly and compiled without any errors. The reason, I believe, is that the whole ' #(set-global-staff-size 18)' is a nested argument, whence the necessity of '##'. I didn't know about this, though. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHadad Nesting cat-6 tokens can get very confusing, very fast.  If this answer solves your problem, you may consider clicking the check mark to the left of my answer.  That not only gives me some extra reputaion-credibility, but it also lets readers know the question has been adequately answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\edef`, which requires making a few control sequence names unexpandable; a lower level interface is needed to ensure `\fig` is a new command.

```latex
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\fig}{%
  \edef\fig#1{%
    \noexpand\raisebox{-2pt}{%
      \noexpand\lilypond{%
        \string#(set-global-staff-size 18)%
        \noexpand\figures {#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```